# Downloaded a Bootstrap Template and Trying to change the default image to my own

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

The image in the masthead of the Bootstrap Template is located in the CSS of the downloaded Bootstrap files, however, when i change the image url to the desired picture and save  it, it does not change the image on the page and keeps the old deleted one, what's strange is that when i add the URL in the CSS file on Chromes Dev Tools the preview does exactly what i want it to do but when i do exactly the same on my actual code in the C9 workspace it does nothing and Bootstrap seems to always locate the old default image even though i have gone as far as to completely remove it from my Workspace? If anyone would point out where i am going wrong i would be extremely grateful.

The Bootstrap CSS

```
header.masthead{position:relative;background-color:#343a40;background:url(../img/bg-masthead.jpg) no-repeat center center;}
```

I am trying to change it to

```
header.masthead{position:relative;background-color:#343a40;background:url(http://www.4usky.com/data/out/94/164852092-the-riddler-wallpapers.jpg) no-repeat center center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 4usky.com doesn't allow hotlinking. You'll need to save it and load it from another location and reference that in your background URL.

Comment: i screenshot the image and added it to the workspace named as a .png and referenced it in the URL and still the image resets to the old one and doesn't pick it up, what confuses me most is that the image it is repeatedly finding no longer even exists in my workspace

Comment: Well, Clearing my Browser worked! I'd originally thought i'd done that, but upon trying again it just seems to be functioning perfectly now, thankyou for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the url path inside quotes.

```
 header.masthead{position:relative;background-color:#343a40;background:url('http://www.4usky.com/data/out/94/164852092-the-riddler-wallpapers.jpg') no-repeat center center;}
```

Hope it does the job.

Comment: I already tried this and no luck, it also doesn't make a diference when i do it in Dev tools successfully without the quotation marks.